# Printing from SAP via the CITRIX XenApp client

Tags: printing, citrix, sap

Is it possible for someone with a CITRIX XenApp client to:

1. Print to a locally attached printer using the SAP ‘LOCL’ definition
2. Create a batch job within SAP and then have the batch job print to a locally attached printer

Comment: Can you make SAP use the default printer of the one opening it ? It can be tricky as you can map the local printer, but in the remote server it will not be displayed as local, but as a mapped printer from the remote receiver.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I think the answers to my questions are 1) Yes (as LOCL will use the Windows print drivers of the local PC), 2) No. Thanks.

Comment: For (2) I did some tweak in the past, but it need admin right. (net use lpt1: \\remotepc\printershared). Or you could try to add a local printer too on a fake local printqueue, and after you add in the port a \\remotepc\printershared map it to the remote printer. (tip in detail [there](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/AdminTips/Admin/AddSharedPrinterasaLocalPrinter.html) (the last tip dont need admin right)

Answer (score 0):

If the Citrix is configured to share local printers to the Citrix desktop, you will be able to use LOCL to print to the local machine as long as LOCL is not set in a different way in you SAP installation. Some companies configure local printers in SAP using other names as well. As for the job printing, it is as well possible in the job scheduling definition. If you need more help, let me know.